# webpack module test the regexp not work

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        exclude: /(^logo\.png$|^logo3\.png$)/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 15 * 1024,
            name: "imgs/[name].[ext]"
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        include: /(^logo\.png$|^logo3\.png$)/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'imgs/[name].[ext]'
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
```

This config can't let `logo.png` and `logo3.png` loaded by `file-loader`
if I change the regexp to `/(logo.png|logo3.png)/` it will be work.

Why does the old regexp not work?

Comment: quite hard regex... can you try this /logo3?\.png$/
Also do not use ^ because file name includes path to resource (i.e. user/app/src/logo.png)

Comment: Yes, I forgot the path of the resource. If I use ^, the test will be false. Maybe you can post an answer, so I can close my question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your regex actually work!
you can head over here for testing you regex pattern online. This is a pretty good page for testing your regex
https://regex101.com/

And secondly, just my though, that maybe your second rule have no test config init.
You could try to add `test: /\.(jpg|png)$/` in your second rule config

Answer (score 1):

IMO you are using `^` which means the filename should strictly start from `logo.png` and internally webpack might have appended the path like `/path/to/logo.png` and your condition `to strictly begin with logo.png` fails and hence your file doesn't get included.

when you removed `^` then `/path/to/logo.png` is valid according to `/(logo.png|logo3.png)/`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using webpack 4:

```
        {
            test: /.(ts|tsx)?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: {
                or: [
                    function(item){
                        console.log('regex match', item)
                        return item.match(/(.*)stories.tsx/)
                    },
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/@types'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/data'),
                ],
            },
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend'),
            ],
            options: {
                // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
                transpileOnly: true,
            },
        },
```

See:

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleexclude
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition